# Does pdfDocument.Save keep the PDF file format?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I would like to know how the save method of a PDF document works.

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filePath);

if (document.Version < 14)
    document.Version = 14;

// add a watermark to the PDF document pages

document.Save(filePath);
```

Does the `Save` method keep the same format from the original file? Let's say the original file is a PDF/A file, will it always save the manipulated PDF document as a PDF/A file?

Btw. yes I tested it with a document and it worked :) Just wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF/A is a standard for archiving documents. For example, the standard ensures that documents do not link to external resources such as fonts that may not be available in the future.

A pdf can be PDF/A compliant to certain standards such as PDF/A-1b, PDF/A-2b and PDF/A-2u.

So, to answer your question, if you open a PDF/A compliant document and do not add any non PDF/A compliant content, it will still be PDF/A compliant after it is saved.